# Unexpected PHP behaviour updating database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This query is not updating the database entry with **id=0000000001** in my php code. After executing this query the database entry remain same as it was before.

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET (itemName=$item_name, description=$description, 
    supplierCode=$supplier_code, cost=$cost, price=$sell_price,onHand=$num_on_hand, 
    reorderPoint=$reorder_point, backOrder=$back_order) WHERE id=0000000001;";
$x = $connection->prepare($sql);
$connection->query($sql);
```

Comment: always try to put the values within quotes `'`

Comment: Maybe its the wrong ";" after id=0000000001

Comment: What's your column length set to; maybe it's too low.

Comment: always check for errors returned after query is sent to database

Comment: Also try removing the `(` and `)` in your query if your column length is OK.

Comment: Why do you both prepare a statement and query with the query function?

Comment: Change to `$connection->query($sql);` to `$connection->query($x);` you're calling the wrong variable. Also do what Lepanto mentioned also.

Comment: since you don't have quotes around the value in where condition `id=0000000001` it will be evaluated as `id=1`, so put all values within single quotes.

Comment: There's so many wrong things in those 3 lines of codes..

Comment: I'm not going to bother putting in an answer. The OP can piece everything together from comments given.

Comment: `UPDATE example
 SET field1 = 'updated value'
 WHERE field2 = 'N';` as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory 
        SET itemName='$item_name',
        description='$description', 
        supplierCode='$supplier_code', 
        cost='$cost', 
        price='$sell_price',
        onHand='$num_on_hand', 
        reorderPoint='$reorder_point', 
        backOrder='$back_order' 
        WHERE id='0000000001';";
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$x = $connection->prepare("UPDATE inventory SET (itemName=?, description=?, 
    supplierCode=?, cost=?, price=?,onHand=?, 
    reorderPoint=?, backOrder=?) WHERE id=0000000001");
$x->bind_param('ssiiiiii',$item_name,$description,$supplier_code,$cost,$sell_price,$num_on_hand,$reorder_point,$back_order);
$x->execute();
```

I am assuming that `supplierCode, cost,price,onHand,reorederPoint and backOrder are of type int`